# update mysql db >> # of binds doesnt match # of tokens (but it does?)

Tags: php, mysql

thank you for your time.
I am simply trying to update some database fields with information if the current ID already exists in the database, However, I am getting an error:

```
[15-Jan-2022 20:49:30 America/Phoenix] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /public_html/_chathandler.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/_chathandler.php(23): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /public_html/_chathandler.php on line 23
```

here is my code:

```
include 'required/dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST['t'])){$t=$_POST['t'];}else{$t='';}
if(isset($_POST['c'])){$c=$_POST['c'];}else{$c='default';}
if(isset($_POST['c1'])){$c1=$_POST['c1'];}else{$c1='#000000';}
if(isset($_POST['c2'])){$c2=$_POST['c2'];}else{$c2='#ffffff';}
if(isset($_POST['s'])){$s=$_POST['s'];}else{$s='lol';}
$id=$_POST['id'];
@$msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);
switch ($t) {
  case 0:
    try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO chatsettings (id, c1, c2, s, dc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $conn->prepare($sql)->execute([$id, $c1, $c2, $s, $c]);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
     if($e->errorInfo[1]==1062){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE chatsettings SET c1:c1, c2:c2, s:s, dc:dc WHERE id=:id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':c1', $c1);
            $stmt->bindParam(':c2', $c2);
            $stmt->bindParam(':s', $s);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dc', $c);
            $stmt->execute();
        //echo "1062";
        return;}
     echo "failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
    break;
  case 1:
    fcmsend($c, 0, '', $msg);
    break;
  case 2:
    
    break;
  default:
    
}
```

As you can see, my bound parameters match the SQL params... but I am still getting an error.
My db columns are `id | c1 | c2 | s | dc`

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you for checking it out!

Comment: Your update statement should be like `SET c1=:c1,...`, not `SET c1:c1,...`?

Comment: Also, your assignments at the top can all be of the form `$t = $_POST['t'] ?? '';` to save a lot of typing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Appreciate the shorter syntax, too :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here has already been identified in the comments as a syntax error in `c1:c1`, etc. However, there's more here to unpack.

You're using the 1062 error to detect a duplicate key, and running an `UPDATE` if the `INSERT` fails for this reason.

MySQL already includes a syntax that handles this eventuality in one query,  [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), thus removing the need to handle an error.

Thus, your query becomes something like

```
INSERT chatSettings (id,c1,c2,s,dc) values (1,'four','x','y','z')
 on duplicate key update 
    c1=values(c1), 
    c2=values(c2), 
    s=values(s), 
    dc=values(dc);
```

Note: this is good for MySQL 5.7. This use of `VALUES()` is deprecated in MySQL 8.0 and will generate a warning. For MySQL 8 and above you need to provide an alias:

```
INSERT chatSettings (id,c1,c2,s,dc) values (1,'five','j','f','k')  as newChatSetting 
  on duplicate key update 
    c1=newChatSetting.c1, 
    c2=newChatSetting.c2, 
    s=newChatSetting.s, 
    dc=newChatSetting.dc;
```

Your PHP can be simplified to

```
    try{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO chatsettings (id, c1, c2, s, dc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) as newChatSetting ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c1=newChatSetting.c1, c2=newChatSetting.c2, s=newChatSetting.s, dc=newChatSetting.dc";
        $conn->prepare($sql)->execute([$id, $c1, $c2, $s, $c]);
        return;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

(This version for MySQL 8. Use the `VALUES()` version for MySQL 5.7)